# Hilt - Field injection returning a null object refernece

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

This is my first time using `Hilt` for DI and I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm trying to `Field inject` my `TestClass` into my `MainActivity`, but it's giving me a null object reference when I call the method of the injected `TestClass`

I've made sure to create an `BaseApplication` class that has the annotation `HiltAndroidApp`

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
  ...
}
```

The class I'm trying to inject into my `MainActivity`

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class TestClass {

    @Inject
    public TestClass() {
    }

    public String getName(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And using `FieldInjection` in my `MainActivity`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TestAdapterCallback {

    @Inject
    TestClass testClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        Timber.d(testClass.getName()); //Giving a null object reference
    
        ...
```

I followed a tutorial off youtube that is doing Field Injection. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here.

[image]

Comment: I'm stupid and only added  ```implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37'``` . I needed to also add ```annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.37'```, ```classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37'```, and ```apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'```.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your problem! When you get a chance, please copy your comment into the answer box as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (aside from the "I'm stupid"; you're not) and accept it a couple of days later. That marks your problem as solved, allows others to find and upvote it, and allows future readers to edit or update your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only added `implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37'` in my dependencies when I needed to also add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.37'
}
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37'
    }
}
```